# if else condition, from contact form

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

I have the following code, which takes the value from a drop down box for Sex: (Male/Female) on a contact form, if the value is male, it takes the user to male.html when the form is submitted, if anything else or female is selected, then it would take them to female.html.

```
if ($sex_from == "male")
{
$thankyou = "../male.html";
}
else
{
$thankyou = "../female.html"; // thank you page
}
```

1.If the sex_from takes the value from a textbox, how do i code it so that if "male" is entered it will take them to male.html, regardless of capital letters etc?

2.If the sex_from takes the value from a textbox, how do i code it so that it will only read the first 3 characters of the textfield, hence if mal/mall/malvtyj is written it will still take them to male.html, else female.html?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) and [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) for this::

```
<?php
$value = substr($sex_from,0,3);
if (strtolower($value) === "mal"){
    $thankyou = "../male.html"; // male
}
elseif($value === "fem"){
    $thankyou = "../female.html"; // female
}
else{
    $thankyou = "../xyz.html"; // no male, no female
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, also how would i code it so "mal" would take the user to "male.html". "fem" would take the user to female.html. And anything else would take the user to "xyz.html"

Comment: Check my edit, i have an additional question

Comment: @user3636420 Sorry, didn't need to edit my anser, since the code takes the first 3 characters, `substr` is enough, no matter what, as long as "mal" is in the first 3 chars it will take you to mail.html

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [strtolower](http://php.net/strtolower) for this, like so:

   strtolower($sex_from) == "male"
2. You can use [substr](http://php.net/substr) for this, like so:

   substr(strtolower($sex_from), 0, 3) == "mal"

Comment: Thanks, also how would i code it so "mal" would take the user to "male.html". "fem" would take the user to female.html. And anything else would take the user to "xyz.html"?

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = substr($sex_from, 0, 3);
if(strtolower($result=="mal"))
{
$thankyou = "../male.html";
}
else
{$thankyou = "../female.html";
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding a little more detail about what your code does.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following ,

1. `if (strcasecmp($sex_from,"male") == 0)`
2. `substr(strtolower($sex_from), 0, 3)) == "mal"`

Answer (score 0):

```
$value = strtolower(substr($sex_from,0,3));
if ($value === "mal"){
    $thankyou = "../male.html"; // if male then do this
}
elseif($value === "fem"){
    $thankyou = "../female.html"; // if female then do this
}
else{
    $thankyou = "../xyz.html"; // for everything else do this
}
```